# Ayuda, no puedo actualizar y avanzar apesar de que mi datatable está lleno en postgresql!

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

espero y se encuentren bien, lo que pasa es que tengo un problema que no me deja actualizar aun trayendome los registros que llena una tabla desde un SP, en postgresql este es mi codigo sql:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.sp_insert_update_poliza(
    param_origin integer,
    clave_poliza integer,
    poliza character varying,
    estatus character varying,
    cbu character varying,
    caratula character varying,
    param_fecha_ini character varying,
    param_fecha_fin character varying,
    param_prima double precision,
    param_derechos double precision,
    param_iva double precision,
    param_total double precision,
    param_provider integer,
    param_pack integer,
    param_tipo_vehicle character varying,
    param_clave_buyer integer,
    param_clave_benef integer,
    user_clave character varying,
    json_vehiculos character varying,
    opcion integer,
    param_json_fields character varying,
    param_premium_month double precision,
    param_vehicle_value double precision,
    param_serie_seguro character varying)
    RETURNS TABLE(id_var integer, mensaje character varying, success boolean) 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
    ROWS 1000
AS $BODY$

DECLARE
var_mensaje character varying;
var_success boolean;
var_id integer;
var_count integer;
var_json json;
var_n integer;
var_json_fields json;
BEGIN
IF($19<>'[]')THEN
    IF($20=0)THEN
        SELECT MAX(cve_insurance)+1 INTO var_id FROM tab_insurance;
        IF(var_id ISNULL)THEN
            var_id=1;
        END IF;
        INSERT INTO tab_insurance(
            origin_adm,
            cve_insurance,
            insurance_number,
            insurance_status,
            insurance_cbu,
            insurance_cover,
            date_ini,
            date_end,
            insurance_premium,
            insurance_rights,
            insurance_tax,
            insurance_premium_total,
            cve_provider,
            cve_insurance_pack,
            vehicle_type,
            cve_insurance_buyer,
            cve_insurance_benef,
            status,
            user_cve,
            last_update,
            insurance_premdev_month,
            insurance_veh_value,
            insurance_vin)
            VALUES (    $1,
                    var_id,
                        $3,
                        $4 ,
                        $5 ,
                        $6 ,
                        $7::date ,
                        $8::date,
                        $9 ,
                        $10 ,
                        $11 ,
                        $12 ,
                        $13 ,
                        $14 ,
                        $15 ,
                        $16 ,
                        $17 ,
                        '1',
                        $18,
                        CURRENT_DATE,
                        $22,
                        $23,
                        $24
                        );

        GET DIAGNOSTICS var_n= ROW_COUNT;
        IF(var_n>0)THEN
            FOR var_json IN SELECT * FROM json_array_elements(json_vehiculos::json)LOOP
                    INSERT INTO tab_insurance_veh(
                        origin_adm,
                        cve_insurance,
                        cve_vehicle
                        )
                    VALUES($1,var_id,
                        (var_json ->> 'clave')::integer);

                END LOOP;
                FOR var_json_fields IN SELECT  * FROM json_array_elements(param_json_fields::json)LOOP
                    INSERT INTO tab_custom_fields_ins(
                        origin_adm,
                        cve_insurance,
                        cve_custom_field,
                        custom_field_name,
                        custom_field_data,
                        status,
                        user_cve,
                        last_update
                    )
                    VALUES ($1,var_id,
                        (var_json_fields->>'cve_custom_field')::integer,
                        (var_json_fields->>'fieldName')::character varying,
                        (var_json_fields->>'FieldData')::character varying,
                        (var_json_fields->>'status')::character varying,
                            $18,
                            CURRENT_DATE);
                END LOOP;
                GET DIAGNOSTICS var_n = ROW_COUNT;
                IF(var_n>0)THEN
                    var_success=true;
                    var_mensaje='Registro agregado satisfactoriamente.';
                ELSE
                    var_success=false;
                    var_mensaje='Error en el sistema favor de contactar a su administrador.';
                END IF;
        ELSE 
            var_success=false;
            var_mensaje='Error en el sistema favor de contactar a su administrador.';
        END IF;
    ELSE IF($20=1   AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tab_insurance WHERE origin_adm=$1 
                        AND status='1' 
                        AND cve_insurance= $2)>0)THEN
        UPDATE tab_insurance SET
            insurance_number=$3,
            insurance_status=$4,
            insurance_cbu=$5,
            insurance_cover=$6,
            date_ini=$7::date,
            date_end=$8::date,
            insurance_premium=$9,
            insurance_rights=$10,
            insurance_tax=$11,
            insurance_premium_total=$12,
            cve_provider=$13,
            cve_insurance_pack=$14,
            vehicle_type=$15,
            --insurance_rate=$15,
        --  rate_type=$16,
            cve_insurance_buyer=$16,
            cve_insurance_benef=$17,
            user_cve=$18,
            status='1',
            last_update=CURRENT_DATE,
            insurance_premdev_month=$22,
            insurance_veh_value=$23,
            insurance_vin=$24
            where origin_adm=$1
            AND cve_insurance=$2
            AND status='1';
            GET DIAGNOSTICS var_n = ROW_COUNT;
            IF(var_n>0)THEN
                SELECT origin_adm FROM tab_insurance WHERE cve_insurance=$2 into var_id;

                DELETE  FROM tab_custom_fields_ins WHERE 

                cve_insurance=$2 ;

                    FOR var_json_fields IN SELECT  * FROM json_array_elements(param_json_fields::json)LOOP
                    INSERT INTO tab_custom_fields_ins(
                        origin_adm,
                        cve_insurance,
                        cve_custom_field,
                        custom_field_name,
                        custom_field_data,
                        status,
                        user_cve,
                        last_update
                    )
                    VALUES (var_id,$2,
                        (var_json_fields->>'cve_custom_field')::integer,
                        (var_json_fields->>'fieldName')::character varying,
                        (var_json_fields->>'FieldData')::character varying,
                        (var_json_fields->>'status')::character varying,$18,current_date);
                END LOOP;
                SELECT origin_adm FROM tab_insurance WHERE cve_insurance=$2 into var_id;

                DELETE  FROM tab_insurance_veh WHERE  
                cve_insurance=$2 ;
                FOR var_json IN SELECT * FROM json_array_elements(json_vehiculos::json)LOOP

                    INSERT INTO tab_insurance_veh(
                        origin_adm, 
                        cve_insurance,
                        cve_vehicle
                    )
                    VALUES(var_id,$2,(var_json ->> 'clave')::integer);

                END LOOP;

                GET DIAGNOSTICS var_n = ROW_COUNT;
                IF(var_n>0)THEN
                    var_mensaje:='Registro actualizado satisfactoriamente.';
                    var_success:=true;
                ELSE
                    var_mensaje:='Error en el sistema favor de contactar a su administrador.';
                    var_success=false;
                END IF;
            ELSE
                var_mensaje:='Error en el sistema favor de contactar a su administrador.';
                var_success=false;
            END IF;

        END IF;
    END IF;
ELSE 
    var_mensaje:='Asigne al menos un vehiculo';
    var_success=false;
    var_id=0;

END IF;
    RETURN QUERY SELECT var_id,var_mensaje,var_success;
END;

$BODY$;
```

Y esta es la pantalla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Anexo el codigo java que realiza esta funcionalidad:

```
public void insertPoliza() {
        if (verificaStatus() == false && estatus == true) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "", "La fecha de fin de vigencia debe ser mayor o igual a la fecha actual."));
            RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("alertaSeguros");
            RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("ocultaMsj(6000)");
        } else {
            poliza.setOpt(editar);
            System.out.println("Citas" + editar);
            poliza.setCve_paquete(cve_pack);
            poliza.setCve_contratador(cve_buyer);
            poliza.setCve_beneficiario(cve_benef);
            if (proveedor == null) {
            }
            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            Map<String, String> paramMap = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
            poliza.setJson_fields(customFields(paramMap));
            poliza.setCve_provider(proveedor.getProvider_cve());
            poliza.setPoliza_status(estatus);
            JsonArray arrayVehiculos = new JsonArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < this.selectedVehicles.size(); i++) {
                JsonObject jsonVehiculos = new JsonObject();
                jsonVehiculos.add("clave", new JsonPrimitive(this.selectedVehicles.get(i).getCve_vehicle()));
                arrayVehiculos.add(jsonVehiculos);
            }
            poliza.setJson_veh(arrayVehiculos.toString());



            if (dao.saveInsurance(poliza)) {
                if (this.editar == 0) {
                    polizas.add(poliza);
                }
                RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("cancelar();");
                init();
            }


            RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("formulario:data_table");

        }

    }

 @Override
    public boolean saveInsurance(InsuranceVO poliza) {
        conn = new ConnectionDB();
        String status;
        try {
            List<ParametersSP> parametros = new ArrayList<>();
            ResultSet respuesta;
            parametros.add(new ParametersSP("int", Integer.parseInt(Session.getOriginAdmActiva())));//1
            parametros.add(new ParametersSP("int", poliza.getCve_insurance()));//2
            parametros.add(new ParametersSP("string", poliza.getNum_poliza()));//3
            if (poliza.isPoliza_status() == true) {
                status = "1";
            } else {
                status = "0";
            }
            parametros.add(new ParametersSP("string", status));//4
            parametros.add(new ParametersSP("string", poliza.getPoliza_cbu()));//5
            parametros.add(new ParametersSP("string", poliza.getCaratula()));//6
            parametros.add(new ParametersSP("string", poliza.getFecha_ini()));//7
            parametros.add(new ParametersSP("string", poliza.getFecha_fin()));//8
            parametros.add(new ParametersSP("double", poliza.getPrima_neta()));//9
            parametros.add(new ParametersSP("double", poliza.getDerechos()));//10
            parametros.add(new ParametersSP("double", poliza.getIva_poliza()));//11
            parametros.add(new ParametersSP("double", poliza.getTotal_poliza()));//12
            parametros.add(new ParametersSP("int", poliza.getCve_provider()));//13
            parametros.add(new ParametersSP("int", poliza.getCve_paquete()));//14
            parametros.add(new ParametersSP("string", poliza.getTipo_vehicle()));//15
            parametros.add(new ParametersSP("int", poliza.getCve_contratador()));//16
            parametros.add(new ParametersSP("int", poliza.getCve_beneficiario()));//17
            parametros.add(new ParametersSP("string", Session.getUserCve()));//18
            parametros.add(new ParametersSP("string", poliza.getJson_veh()));//19
              System.out.println(poliza.getJson_veh());
            parametros.add(new ParametersSP("int", poliza.getOpt()));//20
            parametros.add(new ParametersSP("string", poliza.getJson_fields()));//21
            parametros.add(new ParametersSP("double", poliza.getPrima_mensual()));//22
            parametros.add(new ParametersSP("double", poliza.getValor_veh())); //23
            parametros.add(new ParametersSP("string", poliza.getNum_serie_seguro()));//24
            respuesta = conn.ExecuteFunctionQuery("sp_insert_update_poliza", parametros);
            if (respuesta.next() && respuesta.getBoolean(3) == true) {
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "", respuesta.getString(2)));
                RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("alertaSeguros");
                RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("ocultaMsj(3000)");
                RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("alertaSeguros");
                return true;

            } else {
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "", respuesta.getString(2)));
                RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("alertaSeguros");
                RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("ocultaMsj(3000)");
                RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("alertaSeguros");
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(InsuranceDAOImplements.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(InsuranceDAOImplements.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL, "", "Error consulte con su administrador" + ex));
            RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("alertaSeguros");
            RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("ocultaMsj(3000)");
            RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("alertaSeguros");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (conn != null) {
                    conn.closeConnection();
                }

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(InsuranceDAOImplements.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }
        return false;
    }
```

Aqui el problema es que a pesar de que la tabla de la izquierda del medio ya trae los vehiculos aun asi te pide que agregues otro registro (vehículos), ese mismo mensaje viene de la base de datos, espero y me puedan ayudar, saludos y quedo al pendiente de alguna duda o comentario.

Comment: No parecerian llegar los parametros al SP como corresponde. Mas que eso, no creo que podamos ayudarte. visualiza de alguna forma los parametros a ver si estan correctos

Comment: Hola, buenos dias, ya modifiqué mi pregunta, espero y que con esto me pueda dar a entender, saludos y quedo al pendiente.

Comment: y en el parametro 19 va algo?

Comment: Ese es un json de todos los vehiculos y se agregan a esa columna.

Comment: @cratus666jose ¿será que las condiciones para llegar al `UPDATE` no se cumplen? Te recomiendo leer **[cómo crear una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. explica la lógica que estás usando. mira también [cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Una vez que hayas leído los enlaces anteriores, tendrás una idea mas elaborada de cómo puedes [edit] y mejorar considerablemente tu pregunta. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

era una simple validación en el primer `IF` que estaba haciendo en un parametro en donde era un json que no traia valor(null) por esa razón me arrojaba que necesitaba que se agregara un registro, solo cambie el parametro, y ya quedó, ando ahorita trabajando en otro problema pero eso ya lo veria como lider de proyecto, les agradezco de antemano, por sus comentarios, saludos y buena vibra.

Comment: Por favor, [recuerda aceptar la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Saludos.